# Pandas - Update columns if condition is met

Tags: python, pandas

I have three columns that I'm trying to update the values in. The logic is: If a particular row in the column is blank, I want to change it to say `n` instead of `None`. If it has a value in it, then I want to change that value to say `y`. An example is below:

```
Current data:
barcode dash_1  dash_2  dash_3
ABC123  ABC123  ABC123  None
ABC124  ABC124  ABC124  ABC124
ABC125  None    ABC125  ABC125
ABC126  ABC126  None    None

Desired output:
barcode dash_1  dash_2  dash_3
ABC123  y       y       n
ABC124  y       y       y
ABC125  n       y       y
ABC126  n       n       n
```

I've been trying to do something similar to the code below, but I get the message `str` object has no attribute `isnull`. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

```
for idx, row in barcodes2.iterrows():
    for col in ['dash_1','dash_2','dash_3']:
        if row[col].isnull():
            row[col] == 'n'
        else:
            row[col] == 'y'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set all values with `df.notnull()` and `df.isnull()`:

```
df[df.notnull()] = 'y'
df[df.isnull()] = 'n'
```

Example:

```
>>> df
  barcode  dash_1  dash_2  dash_3
0  ABC123  ABC123  ABC123    None
1  ABC124  ABC124  ABC124  ABC124
2  ABC125    None  ABC125  ABC125
3  ABC126  ABC126    None    None
```

Now:

```
>>> df[df.notnull()] = 'y'
>>> df[df.isnull()] = 'n'
>>>  df
  barcode dash_1 dash_2 dash_3
0       y      y      y      n
1       y      y      y      y
2       y      n      y      y
3       y      y      n      n
```

Comment: Thanks! Simple and very easy.

Answer (score 4):

```
#df.iloc[:, cols].isnull() if you have nan, you can use this , thanks for  juanpa
df.iloc[:,1:]=np.where(df.iloc[:,1:]!='None','Y','N')
df
Out[1270]: 
  barcode dash_1 dash_2 dash_3
0  ABC123      Y      Y      N
1  ABC124      Y      Y      Y
2  ABC125      N      Y      Y
3  ABC126      Y      N      N
```

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thank you for the suggestion :-)

Comment: @user3910919 yw :-) happy coding

Answer (score 2):

The following solution will NOT touch `None`/`NaN` in the `barcode` column:

```
In [102]: df.update(df.filter(regex='^dash_').notnull().replace({True:'y',False:'n'}))

In [103]: df
Out[103]:
  barcode dash_1 dash_2 dash_3
0  ABC123      y      y      n
1  ABC124      y      y      y
2  ABC125      n      y      y
3  ABC126      y      n      n
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be utilizing array methods and pandas functions. Your current error, however, is that you are you using a pandas array method `isnull()` on a single value. Should say `row[col] == np.nan`.

Here is the pandas way as a replacement for your entire code block:

import numpy as np

```
for col in ['dash_1','dash_2','dash_3']:
    barcodes2[col] = np.where(barcodes2[col] == np.nan,'y','n')
```

Comment: Hi, this changed everything to 'n'

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to iterate row by row.
Try this instead

```
for col in ['dash_1','dash_2','dash_3']:
    barcodes2.col = np.where(barcodes2.col,"y","n")
```